# Sending % over REST causes 505 response

Tags: orientdb

ie:

```
select from V where name like '%this%'
```

The server doesn't like it. Any alternative syntax?

Comment: What OrientDB release?

Comment: OrientDB release 2m2. I put an issue on github last night too as this doesn't seem intended.

Comment: Which api do you use? command or query?

Comment: @wolf4ood Both give 505 and throw java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "te" https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution is:

```
select from V where name like '%25this%25'
```

Notice the escape syntax %25. This works with OrientDB 2.0-M2